# Auto creating new datafile in oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have some problem with Oracle database. Before it works like that, if INDX[Counter].dbf file reach its maximum size (8GB) Oracle automatically created new datafile INDX[Counter+1].dbf. But on server wasn't enough size to create new datafile. I increased space on server, I created new datafile manually:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE INDX2
ADD DATAFILE 'D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\profi\INDX18.DBF' 
SIZE 4M
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 4M
MAXSIZE 8G;
```

Right now after INDX18.dbf reach 8GB Oracle wasn't create new datafile automatically. I had to add new datafile manually. How to set Oracle database to auto create new data file after reach maximum size of single datafile?

Best regards

Comment: It works for years in this way or in different way that I don't know. In oracle server I have multiple INDX files and multiple USER files.

Comment: This question would be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for similar portal but I didn't find.